# Разбить строку в Swift

Tags: ios, swift, macos, mac, apple

Есть строка, в которой используются символы " ", "\n", "\t". Как разбить её на массив строк, чтобы разделителем выступал не один символ, в несколько?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678373/split-a-string-into-an-array-in-swift

Comment: Приведите пример входной строки и что нужно получить на выходе. В текущей форме вопрос допускает разные толкования.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let result: [String] =  myString.components(separatedBy: [" ", "\n", "\t"])
```